# How can I find the coordinates of specific image points?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to create a picture of a surgical instrument with all information visible on the image.

I created a code that finds the most right and most left point of the picture and marks it.
The same happens with the mouth of the instrument.

Now I need to find a possibility to find the coordinates of the screw, for example. I want to mark the distal length. Right now I can not really think of a way. I do not ask for a person that does the work for me. I just want somebody to guide me in the right direction.

This is what I have so far. I work with np.nonzero and cv2.
[What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoS3z.png)

Sorry for my bad English. I am not as fluent as I would like to be.

Thank you already in advance!

Edit: By "Mouth of the instrument" (the circle in the new picture) I mean the small front - sorry that is a saying in German.
I added a picture of what I would like to have drawn in. [What I need it to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKVzL.jpg)

More examples
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edSUQ.jpg)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWz2E.jpg)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lck3.jpg)

Comment: mouth of the instrument. ??? can just show in the same image what you want? by just drawing something?

Comment: You can use the ratio. y-coordinate is the average of top and bottom points of the gap (1:2 ratio). x-coordinate has roughly 3:4 ratio from leftmost to rightmost pixel.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I add a picture. - I do not think I can use ratio because I want this to work with different instruments and the ratio is different most of the times.

Comment: @DaliaY You can tag people when you want them to be notified. The examples are the same image but you say there are different scissors. Do you want to detect the screw, or is just clicking and getting the pixel coordinate enough? The question needs some clarification and more examples, if possible.

Comment: @Burak okay thank you! I added more pictures. On them it is visible why the ratio maybe would not work. I need the coordinates of the screw, so that I can put the double arrow on the picture.

Comment: @DaliaY The function yo are looking for is [setMouseCallback](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=setmousecallback#setmousecallback) then. Here is an [example code](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/).